# Reuse of fuel tanks as habitats?

Tags: space-station

So, we've got this huge, hermetically sealed tube of metal nearly to orbit, just to push another huge hermetically sealed tube into orbit, and then we let the first tube fall and burn in the atmosphere... seems like a big waste to me.

Of course all the "furniture" would need to fly in another launch, and the project would need to foresee the dual use - equip the rocket with at least stubs for all the necessary infrastructure. But the heaviest part - the strong walls, the structural reinforcements, the airtight sealing, plus a lot of tubing seems to be viable for reuse once in orbit, as actual structure of the station - habitats, greenhouses, even dumb structural parts like trusses.

Would it be possible - is there any research or projects - of reusing fuel tanks of rockets as structural parts of a space station?

Comment: yes, there were never-realized plans to re-use the space shuttle tanks: http://www.astronautix.com/craft/stsation.htm

Comment: Related: http://space.stackexchange.com/a/3618/58

Comment: Often proposed, never pursued. The STS external tank was *that close* to being in orbit ....

Comment: @OrganicMarble, actually, it was pretty damn close. The OMS can only do 300m/s, so at most the tank was 150m/s from orbit. Very related: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/264/energy-cost-of-bringing-the-space-shuttle-external-tank-to-orbit

Comment: I know! totally agree this should have been pursued.

Comment: The Space Shuttle tank was a poor choice due to thin (fragile) walls, crumbling foam problems, simple construction and very little surplus delta-V to put it in any reasonable orbit (and arriving near orbit badly scorched). I'm thinking about Falcon 9 2nd stage, Arianne, maybe SLS upper stages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as a "wet workshop". This was o[ne of the options looked at for Skylab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_workshop): the S-II second stage would place itself plus a payload into orbit.
Once in orbit, the payload (containing all the equipment for the station: life support, experiments etc.) would be inserted into the S-II hydrogen tank once piece through a large hatch.

Comment: It was also considered for the Apollo Applications Program for the manned Venus flyby mission, which never made it farther than the planning stages. In between that, Skylab and probably a few others, I'm sure there's *plenty* of NASA documentation on the idea.