# What if both SRBs failed in a shuttle launch?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, failure, abort

I'm certain there are several flight regimes where this could happen, and that the procedures should be different for each one. For instance, this is a very different question before lift off than it is at 40km. So, presuming that the SRBs were burning and then both cut out, what was the procedure at each regime, and what would have happened?

Comment: The SRBs were jettisoned approximately two minutes after launch at an altitude of approximately 46 km (150,000 ft). No SRBs reached 100 km height.

Comment: There were no crew procedures for loss of SRB thrust. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/359893main_AESP_G_O_4_P%26I.pdf  Before liftoff, the SRBs were not ignited.

Comment: Fixed the problem

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44537/what-were-the-space-shuttle-s-emergency-procedures-for-an-srb-or-et-separation-f

Comment: @GdD that question is about failure to separate, not loss of thrust.

Comment: @GdD I agree. Related, by not really helpful.

Comment: Your answer had the failure modes and procedures pretty well laid out I thought @OrganicMarble

Comment: How does a solid motor cut out? What are the flight regimes that make you certain they would cut out?

Comment: The only way for an SRB to flame out is by depressurization. Shuttle SRB in particular can not be depressurized in a controlled manner. So the only scenario where SRB could flame out would be the "Challenger disaster", i.e you have much more to worry about than losing thrust or balance.

Comment: There could be engine damage.

Comment: @GdD thanks. Just wanted to make it clear that there were no crew procedures for loss of SRB thrust, and that answer includes some procedures.

Comment: They don't @BrendanLuke15, once lit a SRB burns until the fuel runs out, or explodes, that's about the only 2 options.

Comment: This should mabye be moved out of comments as there are so many comments hhere. Mabye move to chat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they fail to ignite for any reason, then great success if both and not [just one](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/what-would-have-happened-if-only-one-space-shuttle-srb-ignited): SSMEs can then be shut down and the Shuttle stays on the launch pad with the flight over. SSMEs are started before the boosters are ignited. There is some machinery involved in the booster ignition, so it cannot be said this absolutely cannot fail.

Once started, the Shuttle booster cannot be stopped even deliberately.

Comment: Can't the SRBs be unzipped?

Comment: @AntonHengst yes, they had range safety packages installed. So they could in fact be "stopped".

Comment: @OrganicMarble And I suspect that blowing up an SRB right next to a ginormous can of liquid hydrogen _and LOX_ is fairly unlikely to help save the crew or the vehicle (or even the launch pad).

Comment: @TooTea consider yourself promoted to the rank of "Captain Obvious" :) In all the times this stuff comes up, I have consistently said that there was nothing that could be done.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Oh, I only meant to (half-jokingly) point out that this manner of stopping thrust is not going to be useful for anything else than blowing everything up, exactly because I have seen many questions like "why didn't they do X to save Challenger". Sorry if that came across the wrong way. I guess I should delete my comment.

Comment: @TooTea no, it's fine, I was trying to be humorous too.

Comment: @TooTea Actually, I have considered it and my (unprofessional) research suggests that if you were to place a valve between the exhaust nozzle and the solid fuel, closing it would theoretically, (I **emphasize**  the word theoretically), it would deprive the fuel of o2 and cause the flame and combustion to cease.

Comment: @DekoRevinio Sorry, but that makes little to no sense. The solid propellant is a mix of fuel and oxidizer, it does not use oxygen from the atmosphere (that's kinda the definition of a rocket engine and what makes it work in space). Once you set the mixture on fire, it will keep burning until it consumes itself and trying to seal it in a container is just going to make it go boom.

Comment: @TooTea hey, I did EMPHASIZE the word ** theoretically** on the other hand, I have been able to stop a solid booster during a static test (model rocket). all I really had to do was block the exaust port with something, and it stopped. (it kept burning, but did not put out any thrust)

Comment: @TooTea on top of that, you can separate the SRB before it "Goes boom". (I did not think of that during the static test, and it resulted in a pretty charred test pad)